# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. error in my aspnet boilerplate project

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have tried to make custom mapping between my DTO and Entity.
I have tried to use `[AutoMapfrom(typeof)..]` function to mapping.
I have tried to use `ObjectMapper.Map` function in my application layer for my service.
I'm Using Asp.Net boilerplate framework to create a wep api.

Even though I tried everything that I have written on the top, I still get `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`. Error when I run my get method which is about my app. I will be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Show the full error message.

Comment: it is possible that the direction of the mapping is wrong, use `[AutoMap(typeof(...))]` instead,